# Using Google Maps API create multiple services around in Web Application

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I create a search box using: `maps.googleapis.com`.

And continues using this services to create maps show a location.

My problem is: if function `search box` running, function to create `maps` will fails.

I add in header:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Here my code to search location:

```
function initMap() {
    var input = document.getElementById('diadiem_baogia');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }

        var address = '';
        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
        }

        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
    });
}
```

I tried to add maps with code:

```
<script>
  var toadox = "<?php echo $config[0]->ip_map_x; ?>";
  var toadoy = "<?php echo $config[0]->ip_map_y; ?>";
  var title = "<?php echo $config[0]->website; ?>";
  var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(toadox, toadoy);

  function initialize()
  {
    var mapProp = {
      center:myCenter,
      zoom:18,
      scrollwheel: false,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("contactgoogleMap_main"),mapProp);
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
      position:myCenter,
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

The error appears in console like:

1. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LatLng' of undefined`

at this line: `google.maps.LatLng(toadox, toadoy)`.

2. `GET https://csi.gstatic.com/csi?v=2&s=mapsapi3&v3v=26.10&action=apiboot2&libraries=places&e=10_1_0,10_2_0&rt=main.49 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

Seem can't create maps with this API, I don't know how to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

Check following things :
 - Is the google maps API enabled? 
 - Is the script included prior to setting the lat lng?
 - Is the script loading successfully?

Remove callback parameter from your script src. Use it like this :

Comment: I have enabled before I ask this question and the script loading success. I not saw your example.